# Why do projector condenser lenses focus light directly onto the projection lens?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I've seen diagrams for projectors where condenser lenses focus light directly *onto* the pupil of the projector lens, after going through the image source.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the diagram? If not, why does it focus directly onto the projector lens?

I was under the impression that you'd want the condenser lens to form a real image somewhere before the projector lens - that way, the projector lens can image it, like this:

[image]

Comment: what you need is a real image of the slide, not of anything else, so referring to your second diagram, like O to O2. And condenser is just to make a light source. It might also be unwanted to actually superimpose an image of the bulb with that of the slide, as most probably this will lead to an image with an extremely non-uniform lighting. the way I see it, you image the slide and with minimal effort of moving the projector lens, you make this image shift along the projection cone.

Comment: thanks for the response - are you saying that the focal point of the projector lens is on the slide, and the light cone is just to create uniform illumination?

I'm confused why the light cone converges directly onto the projector lens - basic geometric optics that I've studied don't describe what happens in that situation.